# Pyramid static views (js, img, css): AttributeError

Tags: python, view, pyramid, static-files

To serve stylesheets, images and JavaScript files for my webproject I created some subdirectories to Pyramid's `static` folder like shown below:

```
myproject/static/
├── css
│   └── overwrite.css
├── img
├── js
├── pyramid-16x16.png
├── pyramid.png
├── theme.css
└── theme.min.css
```

However, using Pyramid's specific `config.add_xyz_view` methods as stated in the [Pyramid Cookbook](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pylons/static.html) raises `AttributeErrors` for all of those three commands like this:

> python3.4/site-packages/pyramid/config/**init**.py", line 793, in
>   **getattr**
>           raise AttributeError(name)
>
> AttributeError: add_images_view

or equivalent for css

> AttributeError: add_stylesheets_view

and for js

> AttributeError: add_javascript_view

Currently I am using a workaround, which seems to work like a charm (see comments in code below).

Since I am a beginner using Pyramid working with this workaround seems to be acceptable. However, I would like to understand what's the reason for those errors.

The project's `__init__.py` looks like the following:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application."""
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')


    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)

    # raises AttributeError
    # config.add_images_view('img', 'static/img')
    # config.add_stylesheets_view('css', 'static/css')
    # config.add_javascript_view('js', 'static/js')

    # current workaround, works like a charm
    config.add_static_view('img', 'static/img', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_static_view('css', 'static/css', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_static_view('js', 'static/js', cache_max_age=3600)

    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_route('foo', '/greet')
    config.add_route('bs', '/bs')

    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Comment: That page is not officially supported by Pyramid. It is also intended for former Pylons web framework users. Don't use it as a reference to learn Pyramid. Instead use the officially supported documentation and tutorials, listed under http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/#getting-started Specifically, you can refer to Step 13 in the Quick Tutorial http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/static_assets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a [new issue on Pyramid's GitHub repo](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/1890) and [Steve Piercy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425388/pyramid-static-views-js-img-css-attributeerror?noredirect=1#comment52716848_32425388) showed up, that there seemed to be a mistake in the [Pyramid Cookbook](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pylons/static.html), which was immediately fixed after my question here on SO resp. my issue on the repo.

So the correct approach is like the 'workaround' given in my question:

```
config.add_static_view('img', 'static/img')
config.add_static_view('css', 'static/css')
config.add_static_view('js', 'static/js')
```